# Corresponding rows sql

Tags: sql

Can we do this in SQL

```
Col1,Col2
Asset,1234
Date,1/1/2020
Date2,1/31/2020
Value,10
Asset,12344
Date,1/10/2020
Date2,1/21/2020
Value,45
Asset,12345
Date,1/15/2020
Date2,1/36/2020
Value,99
```

I have the asset numbers I want to query, but I would like to get corresponding rows as well.
So, when I write where Asset=12344, I need asset,Date, Date2, Value information for asset 12344.
Never came across this before. Is there any way we could achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Thanks. I put it, since knowing the concept would solve the issue.

Comment: Do you have a ordering column ensuring that the right dat and date2 and Value are under the right Asset?

Comment: this appears to be entirely dependent on the row order, and there isn't an apparent "key" for ordering.  as such, any solution will be open to incorrect results.  ideally, this table structure should be changed.

Comment: Having just 2 columns like you show will not allow you to do it. You either add an id (ASSET?) to all, or use something like JSON to store all data for an asset into a single JSON column.

Comment: Thanks guys. Tried to include identity column but there are some mismatch, Asset  is missing in some of the rows, so python index is kept failing. will try json. So just convert it to json key value pair?